# Terminal Input with timeout (thread + timer + cin)

Tags: c++, qt, cin

I want to start a console-program (qt, c++) and ask the user whether he wants to load the previous settings or set new ones. After 10 sec without input, I want to automatically load the settings.

My approach:

- start the program with a qTimer and an additional thread
- ask the user via std::cin for his input in the additional thread
- fire the timer if there is no input to quit the thread and continue the main program

The problem I'm facing is, that I can not abort the std::cin programmatically. Even quitting the Thread would not abort std::cin.

So I guess my approach is not right, what's the best way to achieve my overall goal?

Comment: `cin` is intended for simple input that works the same on every system that C++ targets and C++ targets pretty much everything. To get a time out on a console read you generally have to use OS-specific functions. On a POSIX system I'd start with `read` and `select` (mostly because I've had far fewer problems timing out `select` than `read`). Under Windows... Gotta say I've never done this in Windows.  But killing threads to end a task is something you should almost never do. It can leave the program in an unstable state.

Comment: That said, I'm just now waking up to the mentions of qt in the question. Go digging through the qt API. Odds are really good that qt has something built in that does this for you or gets close enough that you can wrap it or beat it with a hammer until you get exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

From your mention of threads I'm guessing the intent is to allow the user to enter text at a console prompt without blocking the `Qt` event loop.  That being the case you can probably avoid explicit use of threads all together by making use of [`QSocketNotifier`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsocketnotifier.html).

The following example demonstrates the basic idea...

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QSocketNotifier>
#include <QTimer>

int
main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  try {
    QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);
    QTimer timeout;

    /*
     * Create a QSocketNotifier and let it monitor stdin/std::cin.  The
     * connected lambda just reads one char at a time here.
     */
    QSocketNotifier stdin_notifier(::fileno(stdin), QSocketNotifier::Read);
    QObject::connect(&stdin_notifier, &QSocketNotifier::activated,
                     [&](QSocketDescriptor socket, QSocketNotifier::Type type)
                       {

                         /*
                          * We've received input so stop the timer and read a
                          * single char.
                          */
                         timeout.stop();
                         char c;
                         ::read(::fileno(stdin), &c, 1);
                         std::cout << "stdin: read `" << c << "'\n";
                       });

    /*
     * Start with a 5 second timeout.
     */
    unsigned remaining = 5;
    std::cout << "you have " << remaining << "s to start entering text\r" << std::flush;
    QObject::connect(&timeout, &QTimer::timeout,
                     [&]
                       {
                         if (!--remaining) {
                           std::cout << std::left << std::setfill(' ') << std::setw(50)
                                     << "too late" << "\n";
                           app.quit();
                         } else {
                           std::cout << "you have " << remaining
                                     << "s to start entering text\r" << std::flush;
                         }
                       });
    timeout.start(1000);
    exit(app.exec());
  }
  catch (std::exception &ex) {
    std::cerr << ex.what() << "\n";
  }
  catch (...) {
    std::cerr << "unrecognized exception\n";
  }
  exit(1);
}
```